# Performance issue on Microsoft Azure App services using Symfony

Tags: azure, performance, symfony, azure-web-app-service

We are facing a performance issue when we are using Microsoft Azure App service with Symfony app (a basic back-office app, calling a WS, writing some data in DB and send it to the front app).

To validate that issue is not code relative, we tried on local and on Microsoft Azure oncloud Virtual Machine with same [ACU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/acu).
It's mandatory for us to use App service because of our customer policy

**Summary**

- Performances on local are good
- Performances on VM are good
- Performances on app service are bad
- [metrics don't show hardware issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuTHX.png)
- performance seems to be relative to disk performance and latency when using PHP command (see below symfony specific command)
- **writing on the disk is 1000 times** slower on App service VS VM/local
- when we launch command using bin/console, it takes 8 seconds VS less than 1 for VM/local

**How we test performance ?**

When we are accessing to the front app, performances are bad, we have high latency.

we checked symfony _profiler, `dd` command and symfony specific command

*dd command*

on app service

```
root@09b68d228779:/home/site# dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/site/wwwroot/test1.img bs=1G count=1 oflag=dsync
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 21.9822 s, 48.8 MB/s
 
root@09b68d228779:/home/site# dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/site/wwwroot/test1.img bs=512 count=1000 oflag=dsync
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
512000 bytes (512 kB, 500 KiB) copied, 31.7151 s, 16.1 kB/s
```

on Azure VM

```
user@app:~$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test1.img bs=1G count=1 oflag=dsync
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 10.1442 s, 106 MB/s
user@app:~$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test1.img bs=512 count=1000 oflag=dsync
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
512000 bytes (512 kB, 500 KiB) copied, 9.1723 s, 55.8 kB/s
```

*symfony specific command*

on local

```
[INFO] Starting benchmark                                                                                               
------------------------------ ----------  
 Title                          Duration   
------------------------------ ----------  
 Write inside of project dir    0.3 ms     
 Write outside of project dir   0.8 ms     
 Factorials calculation         5.4 ms     
------------------------------ ----------  
mardi 29 mars 2022, 16:36:59 (UTC+0200)
```

on app service

```
Tue Mar 29 14:34:19 UTC 2022
 [INFO] Starting benchmark                                                                                              
------------------------------ ---------- 
  Title                          Duration  
 ------------------------------ ---------- 
  Write inside of project dir    558.5 ms  
  Write outside of project dir   2.4 ms    
  Factorials calculation         8.1 ms    
 ------------------------------ ---------- 
Tue Mar 29 14:34:27 UTC 2022
```

on Azure VM

```
Tue Mar 29 14:34:09 UTC 2022
[INFO] Starting benchmark
------------------------------ ----------
  Title                          Duration
------------------------------ ----------
  Write inside of project dir    0.4 ms
  Write outside of project dir   0.6 ms
  Factorials calculation         7.2 ms
------------------------------ ----------
Tue Mar 29 14:34:09 UTC 2022
```

**what we've tried**

- scale up app service to P3v2 (840ACU, 14GB of memory)
- scale out app service to 3 instances
- mount external disk on the app service (we can only use CIFS)
- contact Microsoft Azure Support (after a lot of mail, Symfony is not supported by Support)

**Software**

- Symfony 5.4.8
- we are using following packages :

```
 "require": {
    "php": ">=7.4",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-openssl": "*",
    "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.3",
    "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.11.99.2",
    "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.4",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.1",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.9",
    "michaeldegroot/doctrine-encrypt-bundle": "^4.0",
    "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^2.1",
    "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.2",
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.1",
    "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/asset": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/console": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
    "symfony/form": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/http-client": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/intl": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/mailer": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/mime": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/notifier": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/process": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/property-access": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/property-info": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/runtime": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/serializer": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/string": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/translation": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "^5.3",
    "symfony/validator": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/web-link": "5.3.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "5.3.*",
    "talan/pattern-matching": "^1.1",
    "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
    "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.4",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
    "symfony/browser-kit": "^5.3",
    "symfony/css-selector": "^5.3",
    "symfony/debug-bundle": "^5.3",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.3",
    "symfony/stopwatch": "^5.3",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "^5.3",
    "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "^5.3"
  },
```

**Linux Web App Service (P1v2: 1)**

- Runtime stack : PHP7.4
- Operation System : Linux
- deployment using code
- Region : France Central
- Production type
- Size : P1v2: 1 (210 ACU, 3.5GB of memory)

Comment: I would suggest you to use a profiling tool such as blackfire to see where your time goes

Comment: I don't know azure but it look like your latencies can be related to network (network mounted symfony dir) ?

Comment: The project directory that you write to is part of the App Service? Can you check what is described in the File system storage blade of the App Service Plan? Depending on the SKU the throughput is limited....

Comment: Hey Simon, were you able to resolve the issue? We're currently also facing major performance issues with the WebApp/Symfony-Stack on Azure...

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is part of the App service infrastructure and as you mention you have a high dependency on the disk.

App services use a file share and mount it as a network drive which adds latency to I/O requests, this is to increase reliability, but usually when dealing with App service and high amounts of disk operations it is going to be slower than when using a VM or local machine.

Additional to that you are most likely using a standard HDD for the file share (there is no way to choose), I would recommend trying with BYOS [(Bring Your  Own Storage)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=portal&pivots=code-windows) and a premium storage account to use SSD [Storage account overview - Azure Storage | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview#types-of-storage-accounts)

If that doesn't work, a container instance could be the closest thing to a VM without leaving PaaS